# How to specify the ARN of an IAM role that enables API Gateway to write information to CloudWatch Logs in boto SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Manually it can be done when you go to setting on API Gateway page and adding an IAM role (https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=us-east-1#/settings). But I dont know which API to use it for python sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CloudWatch role can be set by calling update_account using the python sdk https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.update_account

The path for the cloudwatchArn is /cloudwatchRoleArn

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works with 'op':'replace' not with 'op':'add'. In the case where there is no cloudwatch role set, will the 'op':'replace' work?
Apparently I cant test that case because once you have added a role in settings it doesn't allow you to remove it.

Comment: You can set /cloudwatchRoleArn to null to remove it.